# How to make each column of the same width, each column center aligned and each number aligned by decimal in a table in LaTeX?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have a table as follows:

[image]

Its code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{cSSSSSc}
\toprule
  \multirow{2}{*}{One} & \multicolumn{5}{l}{\num{2018}Year~\num{0}\num{7}Month~\num{0}\num{9}Day to~\num{2018}Year~\num{0}\num{7}Month~\num{13}day cheak results（\unit{\mg\per\liter}）} & \multirow{2}{*}{Weather} \\ \cmidrule{2-6}
                      & $\text{COD}_\text{cr}$  & $\text{BOD}_\text{5}$  & NT &TP& SS   \\
\midrule
  1                   & 73        & 22.3      & 21.4      & 3.7      & 52     & sun              \\
  2                   & 69        & 18.9      & 11        & 1.3      & 28     & sun \\
  3                   & 80        & 29.1      & 10.8      & 1.3      & 37     & sun               \\
  4                   & 78        & 26        & 10.8      & 1.4      & 30     & sun \\
  5                   & 72        & 19.4      & 10.4      & 1        & 33     & sun \\
 average                 & 74.4      & 23.1      & 12.8      & 1.7      & 36 
    &                 \\
\bottomrule       
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

There are several places I want to change:

1. Column 2 to column 6 are not distributed
2. In column 2 to column 6, the number and the characters are not centered
3. Base on 1 and 2 above, I want to keep numbers aligned with decimal.

How should I change my code to do those?

Comment: Please indicate if it's ok to simplify `\num{2018}Year~\num{0}\num{7}Month~\num{0}\num{9}Day to~\num{2018}Year~\num{0}\num{7}Month~\num{13}day cheak results（\unit{\mg\per\liter}`. Incidentally, what is a "cheak result"?

Comment: @Mico That code is not important, but it is long enough to make the columns under it show with different widths.

Answer (score 2):

The LaTeX tabular environment is based on `\halign` TeX primitive and the `\multiclumn` macro expands to desired number of `\omit\span` primitives which omits (ignores) the columns declaration and spans over more columns. The `\halign` primitive works in more steps. First, it saves all table items in boxes. Then it measures the maximal width of the box in each column (w_i for i-th column), next it re-calculates all boxes in each column in order they have the width w_i (using `\hbox to w_i`). And finally it puts boxes line per line to the outer vertical list. If there is a box B saved by `\omit\span` with a width w (say it spans from i-th column to j-th colum) then TeX does following: if w<w_i+...+w_j then the the box B is re-alculated to w_i+...+w_j width. If w>w_i+...+w_j then w_j is enlarged in order to  w=w_i+...+w_j. This happened in your table: the table-header is wider than w_2+...+w_6. You cannot change this hardwired behavior of TeX.

The best solution is to use shorter table header, as Mico proposed. Or you can add spaces to selected columns manually or by an intelligent macro.

I don't know an automatic solution which distributes the w-(w_i+...+w_j) to the w_i,...,w_j values proportionally. Keep in mind that this task is very complicated in general: there can be more boxes which span more columns, each box spans over different set of columns with nonempty intersection. What box is "a master" which propagates its width to columns? What columns should be enlarged?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l 
                    *{3}{S[table-format=2.1]} 
                    S[table-format=1.1] 
                    S[table-format=2.0]
                    c @{}}
\toprule
  \multirow{2}{*}{One} 
  & \multicolumn{5}{@{}c@{}}{2018-07-09 to 2018-07-13 
     (\unit[per-mode=symbol]{\mg\per\liter})} 
  & \multirow{2}{*}{Weather} \\ 
  \cmidrule(lr){2-6}
  & {$\textnormal{COD}_{\textnormal{cr}}$} 
  & {$\textnormal{BOD}_{\textnormal{5}}$}  
  & {NT} & {TP} & {SS}   \\
\midrule
  1            & 73 & 22.3 & 21.4 & 3.7 & 52 & sun \\
  2            & 69 & 18.9 & 11   & 1.3 & 28 & sun \\
  3            & 80 & 29.1 & 10.8 & 1.3 & 37 & sun \\
  4            & 78 & 26   & 10.8 & 1.4 & 30 & sun \\
  5            & 72 & 19.4 & 10.4 & 1   & 33 & sun \\ 
\addlinespace
 average       & 74.4&23.1 & 12.8 & 1.7 & 36 &     \\
\bottomrule       
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But if I add some characters in row one, column 2 to column 6 are not distributed. Just change " (\unit[per-mode=symbol]{\mg\per\liter})" to  "(\unit[per-mode=symbol]{\mg\per\liter})asfddddddaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"

Comment: @Y.zeng - My mind-reading skills are sadly (but possibly not surprisingly) just rubbish. I am no good at discussing things that aren't known. Do you want me to delete this answer as it apparently is of no use to you?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is much useful to me. It is just that in the future, there are many situations in which the first line is longer than the second line consisting of several columns that will have been set to the same widths. In those situations, I still need to find ways to solve this problem. May you teach me how to understand "\begin{tabular}{@{} l 
                    *{3}{S[table-format=2.1]} 
                    S[table-format=1.1] 
                    S[table-format=2.0]
                    c @{}}" codes? Or could you send me the link about these codes?